# Displaying male and female contacts on map with different icons

Tags: profile

I currently use profiles to display our volunteers on a map in Civi, which is really useful. Counsellors and volunteers are different contact types, so show different icons, which is helpful. However, I would also like to display volunteers with different icons (or perhaps differently coloured icons), so that I can see where the nearest male volunteer or female volunteer is located. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Stuart can you clarify how you are doing the Map as there are both civi and non-civi approaches

Comment: Hi Petednz. I do the map like this:
.../civicrm/profile/map?map=1&gid=20&reset=1

Comment: So I'm doing it from within Civi using a profile

Comment: I don't know how to do more complex config on the maps that way. I would be trying via OpenLayers and Views if you are on Drupal. A chat (without conclusion) about this type of thing is here - there may be other ones in the forum too - https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=23141.0

Comment: Thanks Petednz - I will have a go at doing it via Views, as yes I'm on Drupal

Comment: What would you do about non-binary ones or ones who would prefer not to say?